# How to enable input text fields while scroll is disabled on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, event-handling

On a website dedicated to mobile I’m preventing the user ability to scroll using the following code in document.ready:

*document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {e.preventDefault(););*

This works great but it has a side effect which prevents the user from interacting with input text fields, the text fields don’t respond.

I have tried adding a tap event to the one of the text fields but that didn’t work.

Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Thank you,
Moshe S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use touchstart, it is basically mobile click, use touchmove instead:

```
function preventBehavior(e)  
{ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
};

document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);
```